# How to display decimal value to 2 decimal places in datatable to display in datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a table column `sales_price` of type money. When I am retrieving its value through a stored procedure and the value is inserted in the datatable `dtDetail` which is later shown in a datagrid `dataListDetail` (from a `WinForm`), it returns the value up to 4 decimal places (because of the type money). I need to set the value up to two decimal places.

```
private void createTable()
{
    this.dtDetail.Columns.Add("sales_price", System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));

    this.dataListDetail.DataSource = this.dtDetail;

    this.dataListDetail.Columns["sales_price"].HeaderText = "Sales Price";

}
```

After inserting a value like *50* or *50,5* I expect for the sales_price value to display in the datagrid with only 2 decimal places (Ex. *50,00* or *50,50*), but it ends displaying it with 4 decimal places (Ex. *50,0000* or *50,5000*) by default (due to the type Money).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello Alexander, it's WinForms. Already updated the context and added the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set Format on DefaultCellStyle:

```
this.dataListDetail.Columns["sales_price"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is just what I needed, though I had to change my regional settings to English (United States) because my computer had it in Spanish (Venezuela). To not have to do this, is there another format that can do the same that doesn't use currency (just focusing on the 2 decimals) or any other solution similar to this line that applies to this context?

Comment: I found the format I needed, it works with "N2" or "0.00##" and both display the value with 2 decimal places with no currency. Thank you for pointing me to the right way!

Comment: @DigitalDevGuy - in addition you can set `DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider` to desired culture.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe .ToString("c2") is what you want? It will convert to your systems currency format.

Comment: When you fill the DataTable. If its just for displaying the data, you can use type string instead of decimal. Ie. dtDetail.Rows.Add(value.ToString("c2"));